# How can I get the current date in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I'm not sure if this approach is the best so I'm open to suggestions.
My code is structured as follows:

```
src/
  program1.py
  util.py
jarfile.jar
Dockerfile
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY src /app
COPY jarfile.jar /app

WORKDIR /app/src
RUN python program1.py
```

The main program being invoked is `program1.py` which generates a directory at the same level of `src` of the format data_{today-date}, so `data_20200122` for example. The JAR file is to be invoked by passing this data directory as a command line argument, such as `java -jar jarfile.jar -inputData /app/data/data_20200122`

Since the data directory is dynamic, how can I have Docker generate the dir name? I thought about using a shell script instead but I'm new to Docker and wanted to know if there's a better approach.

Comment: Can you change `program1.py` so that it generates a fixed name, or takes a name as a command-line argument?  Is it creating something like a data set, that you could also create externally and bind-mount to a fixed path?

Comment: @DavidMaze  Yes, it is creating a dataset. I _could_ always change the code to have it read in a name for the data dir via a CLI argument but I wanted to know if this approach was even possible in Docker

Comment: You might run this on the host, and then launch the container with something like `docker run -v $PWD/data_20200123:/app/data ...` so it’s in a fixed place in the container.